# PDF parsing for an eBook app

Tags: uiwebview, cgpdfdocument

Looking for some help on the pros and cons of using UIWebView vs. CGPDF for the purpose of creating an eBook reader app. The content would be in the form of PDF, thus I am trying to figure out which of the two API's - UIWebView or CGPDF would work the best. 
I'm targeting features like zoom, table of contents, notes and annotations, and search.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for search, annotations, table of contents, etc...you have to use CGPDF*. UIWebView does not contain implementation for those.  Even then, CGPDF can be limited somewhat and is generally pretty frustrating :)

On the other hand, UIWebView is obviously much simpler to use.

Comment: CGPDF functions are really only useful if you want to draw the PDF pages as images.  The parsing function in CGPDFScanner isn't very useful in itself to get the contents.